# Sed - Multi-Line Pattern matching after finding first part of a pattern

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I need to use sed to:

## Replace Strings Such as:

`tr("Text");`

TO

`"text";`

`tr("Textfsafasfsfas
safasdfsafas");`

TO

`"Textfsafasfsfas
safasdfsafas";`

`foo(tr("text"));` 
TO
`foo("text");`

### Do Not Replace these Strings:

`tr("text").arg(text);`

`tr("I am some text")
.arg(i do stuff);`

`tr("I am some text")
.arg(i do stuff)
.arg(I also do stuff);`

where it needs to be handled from 1 up to n lines of this.

My current code does not cover the multi-line `.arg` edge case. Any bright ideas?

#### Current sed code:

`sed -i  '/\btr(/{ :a; s/\btr(\([^)]*\))\([^.]\)/\1\2/I; t; N; ba}' $file_t`

### Edit:

`errors << tr("Error: Encountered an invalid token at line: %1, column: %2.")
                        .arg(m_reader.lineNumber())
                        .arg(m_reader.columnNumber());`

is an edge-case that is still an issue at this time.

Comment: it seems like the only reason why this needs to be multiline is due to the `.arg()` usage. Can you do this in two passes?

Comment: As it stands right now, regardless if I have `.arg` not on the first line the `tr` with paren. will be deleted. It would be more trouble than it's worth trying to put that back in on the second pass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat ip.txt 
tr("Text");

tr("Textfsafasfsfas
safasdfsafas");

foo(tr("text"));

tr("text").arg(text);

tr("I am some text")
.arg(i do stuff);

tr("I am some text")
.arg(i do stuff)
.arg(I also do stuff);

tr("I am some text")
    .arg(i do stuff);
```

If file is small enough to hold in memory after slurping all lines as single string,

```
$ perl -0777 -pe 's/\btr\(([^)]+)\)(?!\s*.arg)/$1/g' ip.txt 
"Text";

"Textfsafasfsfas
safasdfsafas";

foo("text");

tr("text").arg(text);

tr("I am some text")
.arg(i do stuff);

tr("I am some text")
.arg(i do stuff)
.arg(I also do stuff);

tr("I am some text")
    .arg(i do stuff);
```

If the output is okay, add the `-i` or `-i.bak` option for inplace editing

**Edit:**

Thanks @Costas for pointing out that `\n?\s*` can be reduced to `\s*`

Comment: `\n?\s*` can be replaced by `[:space:]*`